# Sending image not attached in email of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, paperclip, attachment

I am working on `rails 2 application` where used `paperclip` for upload image.

Once entry created then send email to admin. My `issue` is when call send email `after_create` callback from `model`.

I have to `Send email` with `attachment` image which uploaded but when call send email after create data `get error of image not found` at attachment.

I got this issue because of when call send email at that time `image folder not created` using new entry id. Its take some time so how to solve it?

any one.

Thanks

Comment: This(I Think) is a common problem. When the `after_create` runs the record isn't actually in the db yet. So when you try to find record with the image on it, it doesn't exist yet. I'm not sure if this works the same for creating folders for paperclip, but sounds like a good place to start. Change `after_create` to `after_commit`.

Comment: i checked with after_commit but not fired email. :(

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Are you getting any error messages? Can you post some code.

Comment: I am not getting error but after create entry email not fired which was fire after_create but not after_commit.

Comment: after_commit page redirect so may be email not fired...

Comment: after_commit work but file not attached...I think in attachment takes time so page redirect before attachment so email not fired. Without attachment email fired but need to attachment in it. What i have to do? how to wait until attach file in email?

Comment: Sorry but i got error no file still :(

Comment: I got image now.. Thanks